# (Java, LibGDX, Box2D) Stuttering

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I programed a basic Box2d-"Game": No textures and suchlike, Only a player(body), who jumps from one static groundbody to another.

The problem is that the ground respectively the playerbody, which is followed by the camera, stutters every few seconds.
(https://www.dropbox.com/s/llsg2q65lz828t6/stuttering.avi) (download this video, please, otherwise your flashplayer will show much more stuttering)

If you look between the groundelements, you can see this very good.

Binded textures stutters too.

Curiously: There aren't any stucks in fullscreen mode (config.fullscreen = true); Only on Android-Phones and in window mode.

Although it is only a small game, I have tried to use Interpolation and analysed the GC-actions: No result :\

Thanks in advance!

Some peaces of my code (I turned off the Interpolation):

```
    private float step = 1.0f / 60.0f;


public void show()
{

    //...

    bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(0, 0);


    //...
    ChainShape groundShape = new ChainShape();
    float width = 20;
    float height = 0.25f;

    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;     
    fixtureDef.shape = groundShape;
    fixtureDef.friction = .5f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0;

    groundShape.createChain(new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(width, 0), new Vector2(width, -height), new Vector2(0, -height), new Vector2(0, 0) });

    fixtureDef.shape = groundShape;
    world.createBody(bodyDef).createFixture(fixtureDef);
    groundShape.dispose();

    groundShape = new ChainShape();
    bodyDef.position.set(25, 0);
    groundShape.createChain(new Vector2[] { new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(width, 0), new Vector2(width, -height), new Vector2(0, -height), new Vector2(0, 0) });

    fixtureDef.shape = groundShape;
    world.createBody(bodyDef).createFixture(fixtureDef);
    groundShape.dispose();

    //...
}

public void render(float delta)
{

    world.step(step, 8, 3);

    input.update();

    playCam.position.set(player.getBody().getPosition().x + 6.5f, 3.5f, 0);

    playCam.update();

    player.move();

    debugRenderer.render(world, playCam.combined);

}
```

Player-Class:

```
    move()
    {
        playerbody.setLinearVelocity(20f, 0);
    }
```

Comment: To be honest, I was not able to see any stuttering in that video. Anyway, you might show us how you do the physics step.

Comment: In the last seconds you should be able to see this

Comment: Look between the groundelements!

Comment: It's probably your physics step. Try it like in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848442/libgdx-speeding-up-a-whole-game-using-box2d

Comment: @noone thanks, but I tried this already

Comment: You should keep it that way, currently your physics step is flawed since your game is totally frame-rate dependent.

Comment: If I do this like here: [link](http://siondream.com/blog/games/fixing-your-timestep-in-libgdx-and-box2d/)  It looks so: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kh3qpapem77crs5/with-interpolation.txt) But it stucks anyway. (I would even say it stutters more than before)

Comment: I uploaded a new video with texture: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/llsg2q65lz828t6/stuttering.avi)